# Wordpress custom field for multiple pages

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF pro for creating custom field for my wordpress website. I have a custom field in home page which I want to use in another three pages. Code I have given below.

```
<div class="fm-link-block__grid">
            <div class="row">
            <?php if( have_rows('home-section-modeling') ): ?>
            <?php while( have_rows('home-section-modeling') ): the_row(); 
              $home_section_modelling_image = get_sub_field('home-modeling-image');
              $home_section_modelling_description = get_sub_field('home-modeling-description');
              $home_section_modelling_title = get_sub_field('home-modeling-title');
            ?>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="v-align-container">
                        <div class="v-align-grid">
                            <?php if( $home_section_modelling_description ): ?>
                                <p><?php echo $home_section_modelling_description ?></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="fm-link-block-image">
                        <a href="#">
                            <?php if( $home_section_modelling_image ): ?>
                            <img alt="modelling-image" src="<?php echo $home_section_modelling_image['url'];  ?>">
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <h2>
                                <?php if( $home_section_modelling_title ): ?>
                                <span><?php echo $home_section_modelling_title ?></span>
                                <?php endif?>
                                <i>
                                    <img alt="arrow icon"  src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/link-arrow.svg">
                                </i>
                            </h2>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>
            <div class="fm-link-block-head"> MODELLING </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reference fields from another page, you need to include the post ID. This is similar to how you go about including fields from an Options page.

Example:

`<p><?php the_field('field_name', 123); ?></p>`
Where 123 is the post ID.

For your example..

```
 <?php if( have_rows('home-section-modeling', 123) ): ?>
            <?php while( have_rows('home-section-modeling', 123) ): the_row(); 
              $home_section_modelling_image = get_sub_field('home-modeling-image');
              $home_section_modelling_description = get_sub_field('home-modeling-description');
              $home_section_modelling_title = get_sub_field('home-modeling-title');
            ?>
```

See https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/ as a reference to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if( have_rows('home-section-modeling', 123) ): ?>
            <?php while( have_rows('home-section-modeling', 123) ): the_row(); 
              $home_section_modelling_image = get_sub_field('home-modeling-image');
              $home_section_modelling_description = get_sub_field('home-modeling-description');
              $home_section_modelling_title = get_sub_field('home-modeling-title');
            ?>
```

Works like a charm, I have used the page id instead of post id.